# Declaring a C++ std::set iterator

Tags: c++, stl

The below program compiles fine if I comment the line  insert(s, 10);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void insert(std::set<T>& _s, const T& t) {
    typename std::set<T>::const_iterator i = _s.insert(t);
}

int main() {
    std::set<int> s;
    // insert<int>(s, 10); // line No: 14
}
```

But if I uncomment the line no 14, then I am getting the error as:

> `set.cpp:9:54: error: conversion from ‘std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<int>, bool>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::set::const_iterator’ requested`

Comment: The error says everything.

Comment: If you really only need the iterator, you can say `typename std::set<T>::const_iterator i = _s.insert(t).first;`

Answer (score 8):

The overload of`insert` *which you are using*, returns pair, not const_iterator:

```
std::pair<typename std::set<T>::iterator,bool> pair = _s.insert(t);
```

That is ugly, isn't it?  Use `auto` (if you're using C++11):

```
auto pair = _s.insert(t);
```

Cute, isn't?

**BTW, why does it return `std::pair` instead of iterator?**

Because `insert` might not add the item to set if it already exists. The `pair.second` tells you whether the element is inserted or it already exists — `true` means inserted, `false` means not inserted. The `pair.first` is the iterator which tells you the position where the element is found or inserted.

Comment: @P0W it doesn't save you if you think the return type is an `iterator`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It stills save you, because you will know about your incorrect assumption once you compile your code and see the error message carefully, irrespective of  how long it is. Also, `auto` helps you detect implicit type conversions in many cases.

Comment: I think the error is OP's example is as clear as it gets! Note, I am not arguing against `auto`. It prevents any unintended type conversions, which has to be a good thing.

Comment: @Nawaz I guess what he meant was, that if one keeps thinking that the auto variable is an iterator , it may lead to other mistakes.

Comment: Or if you only want the iterator, initialize it with `s.insert( t ).first`.  (And this is one case where `auto` is clearly bad engineering.  It hides the ugliness of a poorly designed interface, but it also hides the type you actually have.  In this case, for example, rather than getting the error when he tries to initialize the variable, he will get it when he tries to use `ret` later.  And the error on initialization is far clearer than the error he would get with later use.  Using `auto` generally is more of an anti-pattern than anything else.)

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `insert` like it, it uses this overload :

```
pair<iterator,bool> insert (const value_type& val);
```

As you can see, it returns a `pair` and you are trying to get a `std::set<T>::const_iterator`.

You can fix it by doing :

```
 std::pair<typename std::set<T>::iterator,bool> ret = _s.insert(t);
```

(Like Nawaz is saying in his post, try to use `auto` instead)

---

The only overload that return an `iterator` is :

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

Cf: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert

Answer (score 1):

`std::set::insert` used here is returning a pair, but its being assigned to a **const_iterator**

Answer (score 0):

yes, std::set::insert returns a pair as per the docs :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/

so you can't assign the result to a const_iterator.
The extra boolean is to tell you whether the insert succeeded, or if it failed because the value was already in the set.